# How does an LMS store users answers to SCORM package questions?

Tags: scorm, tin-can-api

I am creating SCORM/Tincan packages from html/js and and testing using SCORM Cloud. I am unsure of how an LMS will store user data resulting from the usage of such a package.
Do I need to provide extra coding with the package.. e.g. use certain api statements in order to instruct the LMS to store the user data or is this done automatically? Does an LMS open a course/package in the 'context' of a user and then store his her/results.. or is there extra implementation work that needs to be in place to make this persistence happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question, but I think the answer is 'no' for both SCORM and Tin Can. The LMS will launch content for a particular user. For Tin Can at least, you'll need to take the user information provided by the LMS and ensure the data you store is stored against that user. If you are using a code library, that code library may handle this for you if used correctly. http://tincanapi.com/libraries